# Solucionar REQUIRED de un INPUT

Tags: html

Tengo un registro de usuarios, hay un input así:

`<input type="text" name="username" required>`

Pero si el usuario presiona su barra espaciadora, **burla** el required. ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Puedes utilizar JavaScript para validar el formulario, y que en caso de que haya solo espacios en blanco, no le permita al usuario darle al botón

Answer (score 0):

Para eso ocupa la función de javascript `trim` que básicamente lo que hace es limpiar de espacios un string por la izquierda y derecha, esto permite limpiar de espacios cadenas de texto.

También, usaremos length para contar los caracteres de la cadena recogida y en caso de que esté vacía, devolveremos `false` para no permitirle al usuario enviar el formulario:

Ejemplo:

**JavaScript**

```
function verificar() {

  if ( document.getElementById("nombre-input").val().trim().length > 0 ) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
   <label>Nombre:</label>
   <input id="nombre-input" type="text">
   <input type="button" onclick="verificar()" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes utilizar el atributo [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern)

#### Ejemplo:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}" required />
  <button>Guardar</button>
</form>
```